# Some puzzles about std::basic_string on solaris (x86)

Tags: c++, stl, solaris

Some puzzles about std::basic_string on solaris (x86)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    const wchar_t* s = L"abcdef";
    std::wstring ws(s, s+6);
    for(int i = 0; i < ws.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << ws[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The running result is:

```
97
99
101
0
0
0
```

Why is not

```
97
98
99
100
101
102
```

And the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    const wchar_t* s = L"abcdef";
    std::wstring ws;
    ws.resize(6);       
    for(int i = 0; i < ws.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << (ws[i] = s[i]) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

can get the expected result.
I use `gcc 3.4.6`, build command is `g++ -fshort-wchar stringtest.cpp`. Any one can give an expain?

Comment: This is interesting. On Windows, with Visual C++ 2010, your first code sample gives the second answer.

Comment: Also, g++ gives the correct result when built without `-fshort-wchar`.  It seems to be that option that causes the problem.

Comment: "-fshort-wchar: Override the underlying type for `wchar_t` to be `short unsigned int' instead of the default for the target." It would be useful to know sizeof(wchar_t) and sizeof(short unsigned int)...

Answer (score 5):

The documentation of [`-fshort-wchar`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) reads,

> `-fshort-wchar`
>
> Override the underlying type for `wchar_t` to be `short unsigned int` instead of the default for the target. This option is useful for building programs to run under WINE.
>
> **Warning:** the -fshort-wchar switch causes GCC to generate code that is not binary compatible with code generated without that switch. Use it to conform to a non-default application binary interface.

So it seems that this flag is causing the observed discrepancy, and since the language specification doesn't talk about such flag, the behavior can be categorized as either implementation-defined or undefined.

---

As a sidenote, you should use `wcout` instead of `cout` when dealing with wide-characters, as `wcout` is designed to handle wide-characters:

- `cout` is an object of type  `basic_ostream<char>`.
- `wcout` is an object of type  `basic_ostream<wchar_t>`.

Thought, in this case, the problem is not what you use to print the value, as you're telling the compiler to treat `wchar_t` as `short unsigned int`, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library was most likely not compiled with `--short-wchar`. This flag changes the ABI, although this goes undetected because name mangling does not change.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is `ws[i]` giving the wrong result; the string seems to contain the expected data when I look at the raw memory. It's quite baffling why this happens; as far as I can see, `operator[]` is simply dereferencing a pointer to `wchar_t`, which works correctly in other places (e.g. printing `s[i]` in your second example). The problem also occurs on more recent versions of GCC (I tried 4.6.1), and on Linux.

You can work around it by using `*(ws.begin() + i)` instead.